# text disrupts mouseover

Tags: jquery, text, mouseover

I animate a div when the cursor hover it.
this is working with mouseover (jquery).
The problem is now that the text on that div interrupts the animation because the cursor has no direct contact to the div anymore.

how can i solve this?

```
//navi is the div.

    $("#navi").mouseover(function(){
        $("#navi").stop();
        $("#navi").animate({width:'200px'},{queue: false,easing:"easeOutBounce",duration:1200});
    });
```

The same code is on the text-div.

You can test it here http://jsfiddle.net/rSQaP/17/

Just try to mouseover and mouseout while the red div is animating.
The animation will be influenced by the mouseover action on the blue div.

Comment: Code please? :) (http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#navi").mouseover(function(){

  $("#navi").stop().animate({width:'200px'},{queue: false,easing:"easeOutBounce",duration:1200});
  while($("#navi").is(":animated")){
    $("#navi").off('click').off('mouseover'); 
    //you can add all the events you want to ignore
    //if it doesn't work, use unbind instead of off
  };
  //re-enable these events
  $("#navi").on('click').on('mouseover'); //here you could use bind instead of on
});
```

Comment: I already did (see edit on the first post) but the animation is stuttering when the cursor is crossing the letters.

Comment: its a navigation panel that moves out on mouseover.

Comment: i have tried the while-loop, but my browser crashes.
the problem is shown here (http://jsfiddle.net/rSQaP/13/). in ie9 it is working better then in firefox and chrome so i suggest to try it in chrome. keep the mousepointer in the same high as the text while moving over the div and while the animation start move the mouse a little bit sideways. the animation will be disturbed by the mouse-movement.